Unable to populate my fields using populate()
This is my product.js model
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const productsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Name is required"]
    },
    imgURL: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "imgURL is required"]
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Description is required"]
    },
    categoryName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Category is required"]
    },
    price:{
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "Price is required"],
        default: false
    },
    isActive:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    variations: {
        size:[
            {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Size'
            }
        ]
    }
})

const Products = mongoose.model('Products', productsSchema);

module.exports = Products;

and here's my code:
const Products = require("../models/products");
const Size = require("../models/size")

module.exports.createProduct = (req,res) => {
    if (!req.user.isAdmin) {
        return Promise.reject("Only administrators can create products")
    }

    const newProduct = new Products ({
        name: req.body.name,
        imgURL: req.body.imgURL,
        description: req.body.description,
        categoryName: req.body.categoryName,
        isActive: req.body.isActive,
        price: req.body.price
    });

    return newProduct.save()
    .then(() => {
        return res.send(true);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        if (error.name === 'ValidationError') {
            return res.status(400).json({message: 'Validation Error', errors: error.errors});
        }
        return res.status(500).json({message: 'Internet server error'});
    });
};


module.exports.getAllActiveProducts = (req, res) => {
    Products.find({ isActive: true })
            .populate({ path: 'variations.size', model: 'Size'})

        .then(result => {
            console.log("Found products with variations:", result);
            return res.send(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("Error fetching active products:", err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to fetch active products" });
    });
};

This is my Size model
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const sizeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Size is required"]
    },
    isActive: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
})

const Size = mongoose.model('Size', sizeSchema);

module.exports = Size;

I want to populate my size field, but it seems I am having a problem with the connection of my model (Size) because it returns blank array.
View my Postman screenshot
I already used ref and populate to populate my size field but doesn't work.
Sizes collection: Screenshhot

Please share schema for Size model.

Mongoose's populate method does not support nested arrays directly

I've already added the Size model

,I have posted my answer, Please check and let me know your feedback.

In your Product model add this removing your existing variations.
variations: [
            {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Size'
            }
        ]

Then create Product like this.Try using async((req,res) =>{.. Since my code is aligned with this approach.
const Products = require('./path_to_product_model');
const Size = require('./path_to_size_model');

//create "Size" Documents
 
const smallSize = new Size({ name: 'Small' });
const mediumSize = new Size({ name: 'Medium' });

await smallSize.save();
await mediumSize.save();

//create "Product" Document
 const newProduct = new Products ({
    name: req.body.name,
    imgURL: req.body.imgURL,
    description: req.body.description,
    categoryName: req.body.categoryName,
    isActive: req.body.isActive,
    price: req.body.price ,
    variations: [smallSize._id, mediumSize._id]
});

await newProduct.save();

To retrieve a Product and populate its variations field with the corresponding Size documents do this,
const product = await Products.find({ isActive: true}).populate('variations');

Try this.It will work.
For more information on populate() you can visit the doc link given below.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs
N:B :- In the above code block I have used async-await to get Promise based data. If you want you can change accordingly.

Do I still need to add sizes when creating a product, even though I already have a collection of Sizes? I've attached a screenshot of the size collection.

@das, No ,  you don't necessarily need to add Size variations when creating a Product. The variations field in the Product schema is an array, and if you don't provide any values, it will simply be an empty array by default.Is the above code working?

Still it doesn't populate :(

@das Okay what error you are getting ?Did you make all the changes accordingly?

@das, Does there data(valid ObjectIds) in variations in product model that reference existing Size documents?If there is no valid ObjectIds in variations in Product model It is not going to populate and it will return Null value that you are already getting

@das you can also find the product by id and update it's  variations field.You can do this by this const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(         productId,         { $push: { variations: largeSize._id } },         { new: true }     ).populate('variations');

@das ,I know it is annoying to get stuck to it whole the day but If you have any issue understanding my answer .You can check this link to get more idea about how it works.
https://dev.to/paras594/how-to-use-populate-in-mongoose-node-js-mo0

It works now. Thank you for your help @Subha  :)

@das , You are welcome.I am glad to help you

@das , Please add node tag to your question as well.
